# Selectable Multicast socket (pre 1.7)

Tags: java, multicast

With the advent of NIO most socket types could be "selectable" through the SelectableChannel implementation.  Unfortunately the DatagramChannel does not support multicast prior to java 7.  Multicast **is** supported in prior versions via the `MulticastSocket` class.

I want some way to be able to detect that there are pending messages (i.e. readable) messages on a **multicast datagram** socket. I would like to read until there are no remaining datagrams within the immediate time window.  Having received all pending messages, then want to invoke a callback, **but not individually or prior to having read all pending messages**.

Making this simpler, let's assume one socket.  In pseudo code:

```
List<Msg> received = new ArrayList<Msg>
while (true)
{
    received.clear();
    // initial blocking receive
    data = receive_blocking (socket, datagram)
    received.add (new Msg(data));

    // flush out remaining messages
    for (boolean receiving = true ; receiving ; )
    {
       // non-blocking
       if (receive_nonblocking (socket, datagram))
           received.add (new Msg(datagram));
       else
           receiving = false;
     }

     callback (received);
}
```

The question is how to implement `receive_nonblocking` without NIO 2.  I do not need the Selector mechanism, but wondering whether there is some way I can do a non-blocking read(s) or otherwise detect whether there is something pending.

I had read that to use the selector, the channels must be created directly as in `new DatagramChannel()`, rather than acquiring a channel after socket creation.  So if am correct, could not use the `socket.getChannel()` to create a selector post socket creation.

Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve JNI or timers, pre java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a very short read timeout, and catch SocketTimeoutException, which will be thrown when it expires, and break out of your reading loop.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that SO_TIMEOUT was applicable. Had looked for a non-blocking setting like that on unix ioctl().